# Can I modify the points on an existing path using Snap?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I have an SVG with a path element:

```
<path d="M54.7,0.8 L111.8,73.4 L79.9,126.1 L27.9,128.7 L0.5,74.2 L54.7,0.8 Z" id="Shape"></path>
```

I understand the [SVG path's meaning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths):

- M moves to a point
- The Ls draw lines
- Z closes the path, producing a polygon

And know that I can get a SnapSVG manipulable object with:

```
var graph = Snap(".graph");
var item = graph.select('#after #Shape');
```

But I can't find how to modify a path in [the Snap docs](http://snapsvg.io/docs/). I've looked at item's [paper.path](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Paper.path) but I can't see any examples of changing paths, only new ones.

**How can I modify an existing path in SnapSVG?** Ideally, I'd like to animate the change in paths, ie, going from the old polygon to the new one.

Comment: You can use Element.attr("d") to get/set the path as a string. If you want to modify it extensively you may want to investigate the SVG path DOM though. If you want to animate path changes you could try SMIL.

Comment: Thanks Robert, `after.attr('d', 'pathString')` changes the path. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronized_Multimedia_Integration_Language sounds scary. Is it possible to animate the path changes in snap?

Answer (score 1):

You can animate the `d` ([path descriptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d)) like other SnapSVG items:

```
var graph = Snap(".graph");
var item = graph.select('#after #Shape');
```

Get the existing points:

```
item.attr('d')
```

Then animate them:

```
item.animate({
  d: "M81.8,0.1 L146.8,85.1 L124.1,164.4 L39.7,164.4 L0.6,79.7 L81.8,0.1 Z"
}, 1500, mina.easeout)
```